# How can I optimize a mysql query with multiple SUMS with Case Statements and GROUP by multiple dates?

Tags: php, mysql, sum, case, query-optimization

I am trying to optimize a mysql query that has multiple sums each with different case statements and either group by multiple dates, or loop over multiple dates running the query each time.  Current query execution takes 1.8 - 3.2 seconds EACH time it is run.

Currently I am looping over 30 dates running the query separately each time, even at the fast side (1.8 seconds per query) that is 54 seconds to run the query 30 times.

First, I think if I could have the query group by the given date range this would help optimize things to start, but I am not sure the best way to group by a given date range.

Second, I am sure my table and/or query itself can be optimized.

I have provided the SHOW CREATE TABLE details, a single example of the query, and my php loop that calls the query 30 times.  If there is anything else that can help, please ask.  I appreciate the help AND feedback :)

**TABLE DETAILS:**

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE accounts ;

    accounts | CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `verified` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `active` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `clear` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `batch` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `batch_start` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `batch_complete` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `auth_failed_updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `checking_start` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `checking_complete` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_used` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_tested` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `batch_start` (`batch_start`),
  KEY `batch_complete` (`batch_complete`),
  KEY `last_used` (`last_used`),
  KEY `last_tested` (`last_tested`),
  KEY `active` (`active`),
  KEY `auth_failed_updated` (`auth_failed_updated`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1422229 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**SINGLE QUERY EXAMPLE:**

```
mysql>     SELECT  date(now()) as date,
        SUM(CASE WHEN date(acct.batch_start) = date(now()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS batch_start_count,
        SUM(CASE WHEN date(acct.batch_complete) = date(now()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS batch_complete_count,
        SUM(CASE WHEN (acct.batch_start IS NOT NULL
                      AND  acct.batch_complete IS NULL
                      AND  acct.active = 0
                      AND  date(acct.auth_failed_updated) = date(now()) ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           ) AS batch_died_count,
        SUM(CASE WHEN (acct.batch = 3
                      AND  acct.last_used IS NULL
                      AND  date(acct.last_tested) = date(now())
                      AND  acct.last_used IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           ) AS batch_died_unused_count,
        SUM(CASE WHEN (acct.batch = 3
                      AND  date(acct.last_used) = date(now())
                      AND  acct.active = 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           ) AS batch_died_used_count
    FROM  accounts acct
    GROUP BY  date
    ORDER BY  date ASC;

+------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+
| date       | batch_start_count  | batch_complete_count  | batch_died_count  | batch_died_unused_count | batch_died_used_count |
+------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+
| 2017-04-11 |               4040 |                   847 |              1856 |                      0  |                 1327 |
+------------+--------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (2.44 sec)
```

**EXPLAIN QUERY:**

```
mysql> EXPLAIN (of that query)

+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | acct  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1421996 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------+
```

**PHP CODE LOOPING OVER PAST 30 DAYS:**

```
$dates = array();
for($i = -30; $i < 1; $i++) {
    $the_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-'. $i .' days ago'));
    $dates[] = $the_date ;
    $sql = "SELECT date('{$the_date}') as date, SUM(CASE WHEN date(acct.batch_start) = date('{$the_date}') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS batch_start_count, SUM(CASE WHEN date(acct.batch_complete) = date('{$the_date}') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS batch_complete_count, SUM(CASE WHEN (acct.batch_start IS NOT NULL AND acct.batch_complete IS NULL AND acct.active = 0 AND date(acct.auth_failed_updated) = date('{$the_date}') ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS batch_died_count, SUM(CASE WHEN (acct.batch = 3 AND acct.last_used IS NULL AND date(acct.last_tested) = date('{$the_date}') AND acct.last_used IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS batch_died_unused_count, SUM(CASE WHEN (acct.batch = 3 AND date(acct.last_used) = date('{$the_date}') AND acct.active = 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS batch_died_used_count FROM accounts acct LEFT JOIN networks net ON net.id = acct.networks_id LEFT JOIN servers srv ON srv.id = net.servers_id GROUP BY date ORDER BY date ASC;" ; 
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ; 
        print_r($row) ;
        print "<br>" ; 
    }
}
```

If you have any insight to how I can improve performance I would be VERY grateful.  Thanks for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: FYI: date(now()) =CURDATE(), will save a few milliseconds

Comment: Thanks @nogad, I'll test that out.

Comment: How about table indexes?

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:

1. Build a small table with the dates you need.
2. `JOIN` to that table, replacing all instances of `date(now())` with the date in that table.

The rest of the code is probably OK as is.

Another *minor* optimization is to note that these give the same value:

```
 SUM(CASE WHEN boolean_expr) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
 SUM(          boolean_expr)
```

This is because `TRUE` is treated as `1`.

Plan B:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t
    SELECT  DATE(batch_start) AS batch_start,  -- Note this may stay NULL
            DATE( ... etc  ...
            active,
            batch_complete IS NULL AS incomplete,
            batch
        FROM accounts;
```

Then use that in a somewhat simplified query to go the rest of the way.  I don't know if this will help, but it might make the query more readable.